# How to resize current browser window in Selenium WebDriver with PHP?

Tags: selenium, window, phpunit

When I try

```
$this->size(array('width' => 960, 'height' => 400));
```

I get "BadMethodCallException: The command 'size' is not existent or not supported yet."

I've also tried this

```
$win = $this->window("")->size(array('width' => 960, 'height' => 400));
```

but that just gets me a null object.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the methold currentWindow()

$win=$this->currentWindow();
$win->size(array('width' => 960, 'height' => 400));